# How to write javascript onfocusout/onblue event for @Html.EditorFor in mvc application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My code looks like

```
 <div class="col-4">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
 </div>
```

I am using Javascript in my application.

How to write onfoucsout/onblue event to my Password textbox?

Comment: Hi @Sareka Avinash,if my solution work for you, could you please accept it as answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```
<div class="col-8">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { onblur = "OnBlurEvent()" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnBlurEvent() {
            alert("Hello!");
        }
    </script>
}
```

Or use Anonymous Function

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#Password').blur(function(){
            alert("Hello!");
        });
    </script>
}
```